# add object to javascript array where the list specifies the type

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my program I have an array of javascript objects (my angular model. I am obtaining it from a web service call). I would like to add a new object to the array and I would like the new object to be of the same type as the others. Is there any way to do this other than writing a class and instantiating an object of that type. I mean, is there any way to say "add another member to this list, make it like all the others"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no strict types in JavaScript, everything is an object: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Comment: There is no syntax in Javascript for "make it like all the others".  That's what objects/constructors are for in Javascript.  I'm not sure why you're trying to avoid the feature the language specifically has for this.  Create an object type with a constructor and put one of those objects into the array each time.

Comment: alright thanks. I was just trying to avoid it because these of are objects with properties that are objects with properties that are objects etc. Its going to take some time to write the constructor.

Comment: @user3592739 - you must already have code that makes these objects (since you already have some of these objects in the array).  You should just put that code into a function and make it the constructor.  FYI, you can also [grab some code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704) that makes a clone of an existing object and clone one of your other objects.

Comment: I am getting the array from a web service call. It is passing me an a JSON array. I don't have the code to create the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a constructor function like:

```
function Dog(){
this.age = 13;
}
```

It will take only 1 line to add a new `Dog` to an array:
`array.push(new Dog());`

Edit: 
If you want to get a new object and the type defined in the web service you should first create a constructor function as I wrote before. You can't get the structure in any other (efficient) way

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't be of the same type, would it? I mean if I went ahead and passed the list back to some web service which is expecting an array of type Dog, it would throw an error.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you. I do not have a formal class definition written. I would like to say something like "array.push(new ListType())" where ListType would look at the list and provide me with an object with the same structure as the other objects in the list but empty. Then, even if I don't fill all the new objects properties, I can still pass my list to some web service that expects a list of dog objects

Comment: @user3592739 - Javascript is not strictly typed.  `new Dog()` creates an object.  In Javascript, you're either a primitive or an object (counting Arrays and Functions as objects) - that's what it has.  If you're passing data to a web service, the data is going to probably be JSON which is just a text format anyway so an array of objects is what would be in JSON anyway.

Comment: I understand that. However, and I might be wrong about this, when my web service goes to deserialize the JSON array and turn it into strictly typed objects, I think it will throw an error if one of the objects does not have all the required properties. Will it not?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your problem.
It doesn't solve it the way you wanted, but it's the answer nevertheless